# DB2 - Select rows with oldest date per id and aggregate a field with similar date

Tags: db2, aggregate

Here's what I want to do (Please see photo for reference):

I wanted to select from Source Table all customer (cust_id) and their **corresponding oldest date of payment** (pd_date) and **aggregate using sum() function all similar oldest dates** in result set per customer.

Please see highlighted in *green*, as case 1, *for customer with oldest dates = 6/1/2020 but two payments* (aggregated in result set) and case 2, in *orange* having *no similar oldest dates* thus the result.

[image: select rows with earliest date per customer and aggregate paid amount with all similar dates]

Comment: Please consider reading [this advice](https://dba.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2976/help-me-write-this-query-in-sql)

Answer (score 0):

It's always good to provide sample data as insert statements along with create table statements. Now, the following is completely untested:

```
SELECT cust_id, SUM(paid_amt) as paid_amt, pd_date
FROM (
    SELECT cust_id, paid_amt, pd_date
         , RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY cust_id
                        ORDER BY pd_date desc) AS rnk
    FROM T
)
WHERE rnk = 1
GROUP BY cust_id, pd_date
```